# Airflow Bash command failed. The command returned a non zero exit code 2

Tags: python, bash, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, exit-code

While running an airflow DAG to execute a shell script using Bash Operator, getting error of AirflowException: Bash command failed, getting a non zero exit code 2.

I am using the same process to run other shell script but only this particular DAG is giving the error.

Below is the DAG which I am using for this particular process:

```
from builtins import range
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

from datetime import datetime

# DAG for airflow task
# Email Id of the receiver
dag_email_recipient = ""
# Name of the script which is being run through this DAG. Required to give DAG ID, Task ID and the name of the script
# in the mail body.
script_name = "copy_DAY_PART_RF"

with DAG(
        dag_id=script_name,
        start_date=datetime(2023, 4, 24),
        schedule_interval='50 11 * * THU ',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=dict(depends_on_past=False,
                          email=[""],
                          email_on_failure=True,
                          email_on_retry=True,
                          email_on_success=True,
                          retries=1),
) as dag:
    execute_my_script1 = BashOperator(
        task_id=script_name,
        # Note the space at the end of the command!
        bash_command="""/datalake/SCRIPTS/DAY_PART_RF/copy.sh """
        # since the env argument is not specified, this instadnce of the
        # BashOperator has access to the environment variables of the Airflow
        # instance like AIRFLOW_HOME
    )

    success_email_body = f"""
        Hi, <br><br>
        DAG for {script_name} script has been executed successfully at {datetime.now()}.

        Thanks and Regards 
        Team Airflow
        """

    send_mail = EmailOperator(
        task_id="send_mail",
        to=dag_email_recipient,
        subject=f'Airflow Success: {script_name}',
        html_content=success_email_body,
        dag=dag)

    execute_my_script1 >> send_mail
```

And below is the Error which I am getting:

```
File "/home/appuser/env_airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 188, in execute
    f'Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code {result.exit_code}.'
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 2.
[2023-06-21, 11:08:51 IST] {taskinstance.py:1288} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=copy_DAY_PART_RF, task_id=copy_DAY_PART_RF, execution_date=20230621T051636, start_date=20230621T053053, end_date=20230621T053851
[2023-06-21, 11:08:51 IST] {logging_mixin.py:109} WARNING - /home/appuser/env_airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py:108 PendingDeprecationWarning: Fetching SMTP credentials from configuration variables will be deprecated in a future release. Please set credentials using a connection instead.
[2023-06-21, 11:08:51 IST] {email.py:214} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2023-06-21, 11:08:52 IST] {email.py:226} INFO - Sent an alert email to ['']
[2023-06-21, 11:08:52 IST] {email.py:214} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2023-06-21, 11:08:52 IST] {email.py:226} INFO - Sent an alert email to ['']
[2023-06-21, 11:08:52 IST] {taskinstance.py:1825} ERROR - Failed to send email to: ['']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/appuser/env_airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1340, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/home/appuser/env_airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1477, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/home/appuser/env_airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1538, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/home/appuser/env_airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 188, in execute
    f'Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code {result.exit_code}.'
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 2.
```

Comment: I don't know _airflow_, but my naive guess would be, that copy.sh rally exited with status code 2.